# Page refresh after done loading, add up variable

Tags: php, loops, refresh

```
$test = $_GET['nr'];
    $class = new class;
    echo $class->function($test);
```

I want `$test` to increase after it have fully loaded the page.

The problem is, I don't know how. Looping $test normally will show me a lot of errors. like `function cannot be declared again` I've have the same functions names with different functionality. And it's pretty long code.

Anyone have any idea how I can do this?
Thanks.

EDIT:

When the page is fully loaded, I want it to add + 1 to `$test` and then refresh it with the new variable.

I can do this manually by:

```
$next = $test + 1;
    echo "<a href='/index.php?nr=". $next . "'>Next page</a>";
```

Comment: We need more code to help you with this, you haven't even included an example of what your mysterious loop might be doing...

Comment: @DaveRandom Added more information.

Comment: What do you mean by `after it have fully loaded the page`? Php runs on the server. What loads the page?

Comment: @George Kastrinis By `fully loaded` I mean that the site is done loading. Like the earth in IE is spinning. when it's done it stops spinning.

Comment: Yeah that happens in the browser. In your pc. Not in the server where php runs. You need javascript for client-side code.

Comment: @George Kastrinis Yes, I will let me computer stay on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing the page in a string variable and outputting at the end you can just do a meta refresh:

```
$next = $test + 1;
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5; url=/index.php?nr=$next\">";
```

...will refresh the page 5 seconds after loading completes.

Failing that, you can do a simple javascript refresh:

```
$next = $test + 1;
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nfunction reloadPage() {\nwindow.location.href = '/index.php?nr=$next';\n}\nsetTimeout(reloadPage,5000);\n</script>";
```

Comment: I tried the first one and it got me to the same page, weird. I'll try the second and report back. Thanks!

Comment: There was an error in your first method, fixed it and it worked. Thanks for helping.

Comment: No worries, out of interest what was the problem? I can't see one... Although I did fail to mention that it must go in the `<head>`

Comment: No space between `content=\"5; url=` I think that was the problem.